# Defining nested unbounded generic types

Tags: c#, generics

Suppose I have an interface: `IFoo<T1,T2>` and a class `Moo<T1> : IFoo<List<T1>, Stack<T1>>`.

At runtime I can call: `typeof(Moo<>).GetInterfaces()` and it gives me an array with one type in it, so I guess that in some sense the type `typeof(IFoo<List<>, Stack<>>)` can be created at runtime. However, that syntax does not work.

What is the correct syntax to define that type at runtime?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I guess that in some sense the type `typeof(IFoo<List<>, Stack<>>)` can be created at runtime.

Though that statement is *true*, your logic is not *sound* because the true conclusion does not follow logically from the premise you've stated. The type returned by

```
typeof(Moo<>).GetInterfaces()[0]
```

is not `IFoo<T1, T2>` constructed with `List<>` and `Stack<>` in the first place.

Rather, it is `IFoo<T1, T2>` constructed with `List<T1>` and `Stack<T1>`, where `T1` is the `T1` of `Moo<T1>`, not the `T1` of `IFoo<T1, T2>`. When making sample code to discuss type construction, I strongly discourage you from making type parameters that are logically different but have the same name. It is very confusing.

In case that is not clear, let's take a step back. Every generic type has an associated type called its *instance type*, which is the generic type constructed with its own type parameters. That is, when you say:

```
class C<T>
{
    Type type1 = typeof(C<T>);
    Type type2 = typeof(C<>);
}
```

From **the compiler's** perspective, the *types* `C<>` and `C<T>` are the same type. But these will be **different type objects at runtime** because of course at runtime there will never be an instance of `C<T>`, only `C<int>` or `C<string>` or whatever. The first `typeof` syntax gives you the type *as it is constructed at runtime*. The second gives you the instance type *from the perspective of the compiler*.

So let's consider your case in more detail. Suppose you have:

```
interface I<T, U> {}
class C<V> {}
class D<W> {}
class E<X> : I<C<X>, D<X>> {}
```

then `typeof(E<>).GetInterfaces()[0]` is the type *as it is known to the compiler*, namely, `I<C<X>, D<X>>`.  But `I<C<>, D<>>` is a completely different type; that is `I<C<V>, D<W>>` which is not at all the same type from the compiler's perspective.

> What is the correct syntax to define that type at runtime?

There is none.

There is no C# `typeof` syntax that produces the type "generic type constructed with type arguments that are the instance types of other generic types". That would be:

```
typeof(I<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(C<>), typeof(D<>))
```

To give you `I<C<V>, D<W>>`.

Nor is there a `typeof` syntax for "generic type constructed with the type parameters of a different generic type". kvb's answer gives the Reflection code needed to build `I<C<X>, D<X>>`.

I am curious as to why you would want to construct such a bizarre type in the first place. What's your application?

Comment: >> I strongly discourage you from making type parameters that are logically different but have the same name. It is very confusing. -- Agreed

Comment: >> I am curious as to why you would want to construct such a bizarre type in the first place. What's your application? -- I was registering the type 'Moo<>' as a generic type with Autofac. I wanted to register it as the interface 'IFoo<List<>, Stack<>>'. Autofac lets you do that using the `AsImplementedInterfaces()` method and it all auto-magically works, but I was curious as to how to state my intent explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you would have to use `typeof(IFoo<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(List<>), typeof(Stack<>));`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot really define it in that detail. You can define the basis of the type and then extend it, like so:

```
Type d1 = typeof(IFoo<,>);
Type constructed = d1.MakeGenericType(typeof(List<>), typeof(Stack());
```

Answer (score 1):

That is likely what you're looking for:

```
typeof(IFoo<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(List<>),typeof(Stack<>))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure I understand what you're asking, but

```
var t1 = typeof(Moo<>).GetGenericArguments()[0];
var t = typeof(IFoo<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(t1), typeof(Stack<>).MakeGenericType(t1));
```

should give the same result as `typeof(Moo<>).GetInterfaces()[0]`.